# How to populate an environment in R

Tags: r, environment

I'm using the `IMIS` package (Incremental Mixture Importance Sampling) to estimate parameters. Unfortunately, it's written to look for functions `likelihood`, `sample.prior`, and `prior` in the environment it's called in, so I can't wrap it in a function (my end goal). The univariate example from `?IMIS` works just fine,

```
require(IMIS)
likelihood <- function(theta) exp(-1*sin(3*theta)*sin(theta^2) - 0.1*theta^2)
prior <- function(theta) dnorm(theta, 0, 5)
sample.prior <- function(n) rnorm(n, 0, 5)
result = IMIS(500, 3000, 100, 10)

## also fine using do.call (pertinent below)
result <- do.call(IMIS, args = list(B = 500, B.re = 3000, number_k = 100, D = 10))
```

but unsurprisingly, wrapping it in a function does not:

```
rm(likelihood, prior, sample.prior, result)
imisWrap <- function() {
    likelihood <- function(theta) exp(-1*sin(3*theta)*sin(theta^2) - 0.1*theta^2)
    prior <- function(theta) dnorm(theta, 0, 5)
    sample.prior <- function(n) rnorm(n, 0, 5)
    result = IMIS(500, 3000, 100, 10)
    return(result)
}
imisWrap() ## can't find sample.prior
```

I *think* the way around this is to create an environment in my wrapper (or use its environment) and then use `do.call` to run `IMIS` in that environment, but I don't know how to create a new environment that has `likelihood`, `prior`, `sample.prior`, and `result` in it.

---

**Edit:** Using @BenBolker's excellent comments I have an improved but still not working attempt:

```
imisWrap2 <- function() {
    likelihood <- function(theta) exp(-1*sin(3*theta)*sin(theta^2) - 0.1*theta^2)
    prior <- function(theta) dnorm(theta, 0, 5)
    sample.prior <- function(n) rnorm(n, 0, 5)
    imisEnv <- new.env()
    assign("likelihood", likelihood, envir = imisEnv)
    assign("sample.prior", sample.prior, envir = imisEnv)
    assign("prior", prior, envir = imisEnv)
    result = do.call(IMIS,
                     args = list(B = 500, B.re = 3000, number_k = 100, D = 10),
                     envir = imisEnv)
    return(result)
}
```

But this still can't find the functions.

Comment: I think you can use `assign` to populate environments.  Have you considered asking the package authors to rewrite things a bit  more sanely ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker Or just use `trace` to rewrite the function in real-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put `environment(IMIS) <- environment()` at the top of `imisWrap` to get it to work. This only modifies the behavior of `IMIS` in `imisWrap`. The version of the function in the package namespace is unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it to work by `attach`ing the enviromnent (and `detach`ing after use to clean up):

```
imisWrap() <- function() {
    imisList <- list(
      likelihood = function(theta) exp(-1*sin(3*theta)*sin(theta^2) - 0.1*theta^2),
      prior = function(theta) dnorm(theta, 0, 5),
      sample.prior = function(n) rnorm(n, 0, 5)
    )
    imisEnv <- as.environment(imisList)
    attach(imisEnv)
    result = IMIS(500, 3000, 100, 10)
    detach(imisEnv)
    return(result)
}

imisWrap()
[1] "5000 likelihoods are evaluated in 0 minutes"
[1] "Stage   MargLike   UniquePoint   MaxWeight   ESS"
[1]    1.000   -0.806 1796.246    0.001 2434.921
[1] "maximum posterior= -1.96 , likelihood= 0.61 , prior= -2.57 , time used= 0 minutes, convergence= 0"
...
```

However, I echo @BenBolker in that it really is an issue with the function that the package author should resolve more cleanly.